# Error while compiling RInside code

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rinside

I want to compile a R code using RInside. But I am getting errors while using the function read.csv. The code snippet is given below:

```
include "RInside.h"
include <iomanip>  
include <iostream>  
include <fstream>  
include <string>    
include <vector>   
include <sstream>    
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{   
 RInside R(argc,argv);  
 SEXP ans;  
 R.parseEvalQ("library(plotrix)");  
 R.parseEvalQ("fileContents<-read.csv("/home/nibha/manoj/test.csv")");  
 R.parseEvalQ("nr <-nrow (filecontents)");  
 R.parseEvalQ("nc <-ncol (filecontents)");  
}
```

I am getting the errors as follows:

```
: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:  
prog3.cpp:14: error: ‘home’ was not declared in this scope  
prog3.cpp:14: error: ‘nibha’ was not declared in this scope  
prog3.cpp:14: error: ‘manoj’ was not declared in this scope  
prog3.cpp:14: error: ‘test’ was not declared in this scope  
prog3.cpp:20: error: ‘myfile’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: I think you have no background in c.If you had before looking in console, you would realize that "gedit"(text editor) try to say something over coloring words.

Comment: Rember that this is not compilation of R code, only embedding it to C++ code -- this will not work faster or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You have double quote `"` inside double-quoted string

```
R.parseEvalQ("fileContents<-read.csv("/home/nibha/manoj/test.csv")");
```

So, just escape it with backslash `\`, and try again.

```
R.parseEvalQ("fileContents<-read.csv(\"/home/nibha/manoj/test.csv\")");
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. That was a silly thing to miss out on. Its working fine now.